# Compare between strings in query statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have this table:

```
id         value
AA000001   500
AA000002   1000
AA000003   1500
AA000004   2000
AA000005   2500
AA000006   3000
AA000007   3500
```

The type of id is a string and I use below sql statement to query my record:

```
SELECT sum(value), max(value), min(value) FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN 'AA000001' AND 'AA000007'
```

And it's works as expected. But I wonder if there are any exceptions in this query?

I'm using Oracle 10g Release 2 and 11g Release 2.

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "exceptions".  Your query is:

```
SELECT sum(value), max(value), min(value)
FROM my_table
WHERE id BETWEEN 'AA000001' AND 'AA000007';
```

It will match anything between these values.  In addition to what is in your table, it will match, say, 'AA000003ZYW243'.  You are safe that all matches will start with 'AA00000'.  The next character will be between '1' and '7', and then anything can follow that (unless that character is a '7').

Comment: In my table the length of column ID is fixed. And I'm very happy for this sentence "You are safe that all matches will start with 'AA00000'. The next character will be between '1' and '7". Thanks for your answer.